# What's the initiator level of a Paladin (7)/Crusader(2)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, paladin, tome-of-battle

The question is pretty simple. Multiclass characters get half their non-martial adept levels + full martial adept levels for initiator level. However, what happens when the level is odd? Do you round up or down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your initiator level is 5.**

Every class apart from your martial adept class counts as half for your initiator level as you mentioned. But how to divide the odd numbers? Rounding it down.

Tome of Battle, pg. 39:

> For example, a 7th-level crusader/5th-level swordsage has an initiator
> level of 9th for determining the highestlevel maneuvers he can take as
> a crusader. As a result, he can take 5th-level crusader maneuvers. As
> a swordsage, his initiator level is 8th, allowing him to take
> 4th-level swordsage maneuvers.

As you can see, both of the different classes in the example are odd and they are rounded down (like basically everything else on D&D 3.5) to determine each class initiator level.

Comment: A link to [Rounding Fractions](http://dndsrd.net/basics.html#rounding-fractions) might help, too.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I was just about to link the same thing.

Comment: It may be worth noting that a 1st-level non-initiator is almost universally allowed to take Martial Study and Martial Stance feats, despite ⌊½×1⌋ = 0 and 1st-level maneuvers and stances requires IL 1st. This probably *isn’t* RAW, and I’m sure there are people out there who run it strictly and require those feats to wait until 3rd for non-initiators, but in online discussions you almost never see that as a consideration.